# What encoding to use for Zip archive comments?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, zip, archive, codepages

What encoding is supposed to be used for Zip *archive* comments? I know that the encoding of *file* comments (and file names) are determined by Bit 11 of the files' General Purpose Bit Flags. However, there is nothing like that for Zip *archive* comments, which are stored in the "End of Central Directory Records".

I'm pretty sure that the encoding has to be either IBM Code Page 437 or UTF-8; but how do you know which one? Is it always CP437, even if all the files names/comments in the archive are encoded in UTF-8?

I've read what the [Zip file specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) has to say about it. Unfortunately, it doesn't go into much detail about ".ZIP File Comment". I've also searched the Internet and Stack Overflow; though there is lots of information about file names and comments within a Zip file, I couldn't find anything about Zip *archive* comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as you stated, ZIP APPNOTE doesn't say anything about this.
The best thing you can try is to use PkWare's SecureZIP and add some comments with non-ascii characters and see how they will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Just for later reference:

> The latest ZIP format specification supports Unicode file names. Names
> must be encoded in UTF-8, and the 11th bit in the general purpose
> flags field (2 bytes at offset 6) must be set.

So I would use UTF-8 for comment field(s) as well.

- https://superuser.com/questions/1321371/proper-encoding-for-file-names-in-zip-archives-created-in-windows-and-unpacked-i
- [Correctly decoding zip entry file names -- CP437, UTF-8 or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261347/correctly-decoding-zip-entry-file-names-cp437-utf-8-or)

A good wealth of information:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/495880