# Python subprocess Popen: Send binary data to C++ on Windows

Tags: windows, stream, binary, pipe, popen

After three days of intensive googleing and stackoverflowing I more or less got my program to work. I tried a lot of stuff and found a lot of answers somehow connected to my problem, but no working solution. Sry should I have missed the right page!! I'm looking forward to comments and recommendations.

Task:

- Send binary data (floats) from python to C++ program, get few floats back
- Data is going to be 20ms soundcard input, latency is a bit critical
- Platform: Windows (only due to drivers for the soundcard...)
- Popen with pipes, but without communicate, because I want to keep the C++ program opened

The whole thing worked just fine on ubuntu with test data. On Windows I ran into the binary stream problem: Windows checks the float stream for EOF character and finds it randomly. Then everything freezes, waiting for instream data which is just behind the "eof" wall. Or so I picture it.

In the end these two things were necessary:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

and

```
if (_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY) == -1) 
  {cout << "binary mode problem" << endl; return 1;};
```

in C++ as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa298581%28v=vs.60%29.aspx.

- cin.ignore() freezes using binary mode! Guess since there's no eof anymore. Did not try/think about this too thoroughly though
- cin.read(mem,sizeof(float)*length) does the job, since I know the length of the data stream
- Compiled with MinGW

and in the Python code same thing! (forgot this first, cost me a day):

```
if sys.platform.find("win") > -1:
  import msvcrt,os      
  process = subprocess.Popen("cprogram.exe",stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=2**12)
  msvcrt.setmode(process.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

and

```
process.stdin.write(data.tostring())
```

Comment: It seems your question contains the answer (enable binary mode for the pipes). You should post it as an answer instead. [It is even encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Calling `msvcrt.setmode` shouldn't be necessary. subprocess already opens the pipe in binary mode via `self.stdin = os.fdopen(msvcrt.open_osfhandle(p2cwrite.Detach(), 0), 'wb', bufsize)`. The flag value of 0 passed to `open_osfhandle` is effectively the same as using `O_BINARY` since `_write` checks the CRT file handle for text mode and otherwise assumes binary mode.

Comment: Indeed if you checked `oldmode = msvcrt.setmode(process.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)` you'd see that `oldmode == os.O_BINARY`  because that's what the CRT returns as the 'effective' mode when the file isn't in a text mode (ANSI or Unicode) and `O_BINARY` isn't explicitly set.

Comment: @eryksun: [Python's own `subprocess` tests use `mscvcrt.setmode`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/test/test_subprocess.py#l28). It means it had been necessary at least in the past.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, that's operating on `sys.stdout` in the script for the child process. The CRT uses text mode on `stdout` even when it's a pipe/file. For example, this should raise an assertion error `py -2 -c "import os, sys, msvcrt; assert msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY) == os.O_BINARY" | more` because the current mode is `O_TEXT` even though `stdout` is piped to `more`.

Comment: @eryksun: notice that OP calls the C++ analog `_setmode()` (the child is written in C++ here).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I didn't say the `_setmode` call on the C++ side is redundant.

Comment: @eryksun: I agree `setmode` on `process.stdin.fileno()` might be unnecessary. Do you know is it true for all subprocess versions starting with Python 2.4?

Comment: @eryksun You are right, setmode seem to be not necessary! Thx for the hint.Seems I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question ;-).