# Rolling screen capture with ffmpeg on windows

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have the following code to capture a video stream from my webcam. I use ffmpeg to write to named windows pipe, then read it with python and display with opencv. The thing is that the opencv stream is 'rolling' as shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H78TRo3DZIo

If I capture the output to a video instead of a pipe, with the command:

`ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -i video="USB Video" -c:v copy out.avi`

everything looks fine. What should I change to achieve the desired effect? (non-rolling stream)

My code below:

```
import cv2
import time
import subprocess
import numpy as np

w, h = 800, 600

# Get frame generator
gen = ffmpegGrab()

# Get start time
start = time.time()

# Read video frames from ffmpeg in loop
nFrames = 0
cmd = 'C:/Users/......./Downloads/ffmpeg-4.3.1-2020-11-19-full_build/bin/ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -framerate 60 -video_size 800x600 -i video="USB Video" -pix_fmt bgr24 -vcodec rawvideo -f image2pipe -'

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, bufsize=10**9)
while True:
    # Read next frame from ffmpeg

    frame = proc.stdout.read(w * h * 3)
    frame = np.frombuffer(frame, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((h, w, 3))
    cv2.imshow('screenshot', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

    fps = nFrames / (time.time() - start)
    print(f'FPS: {fps}')

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I would suggest using the d3dshot package https://pypi.org/project/d3dshot/

Comment: your issue stems from windows pipes doing automatic newline conversion, unless explicitly opened as "binary". that is why your video data loses/gains bytes and "rolls".

Comment: also this is really not an OpenCV issue so kindly modify the tags.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz how would you go about opening an explicitly binary pipe on windows in python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943943/python-subprocess-popen-send-binary-data-to-c-on-windows

Comment: if you are only after desktop screen capture, I would strongly suggest not using a subprocess and piping enormous amounts of data around. that costs resources (CPU). d3dshot does it a lot cheaper.  if you are after reading from a webcam, again I would suggest NOT running that through a pipe but using OpenCV's VideoCapture to open the device

Comment: The thing is I want to capture game screen that gets 'blacked out' by anti cheat software when capturing with d3dshot, mss etc. So I cant use those. I could use opencv but I cant get it to return any more than 5 fps at 1080p, which is tool low for me

Comment: also, everything works as intended after explicitly opening a binary pipe, thanks!