# Encoding issue on subprocess.Popen args

Tags: windows, python-2.7, encoding, subprocess

Yet another encoding question on Python.

**How can I pass non-ASCII characters as parameters on a [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) call?**

My problem is not on the stdin/stdout as the majority of other questions on StackOverflow, but passing those characters in the `args` parameter of Popen.

Python script used for testing:

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'C:\Python27\python.exe C:\path_to\script.py -n "Testç on ã and ê"'

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output, err = process.communicate()
result = process.wait()

print result, '-', output
```

For this example call, the `script.py` receives `TestÃ§ on Ã£ and Ãª`. If I copy-paste this same command string on a CMD shell, it works fine.

What I've tried, besides what's described above:

1. Checked if all Python scripts are encoded in UTF-8. They are.
2. Changed to unicode (`cmd = u'...'`), received an `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 128: ordinal not in range(128)` on line 5 (`Popen` call).
3. Changed to `cmd = u'...'.decode('utf-8')`, received an `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 128: ordinal not in range(128)` on line 3 (`decode` call).
4. Changed to `cmd = u'...'.encode('utf8')`, results in `TestÃ§ on Ã£ and Ãª`
5. Added `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` env. variable with no luck.

Looking on tries 2 and 3, it seems like `Popen` issues a `decode` call internally, but I don't have enough experience in Python to advance based on this suspicious.

Environment: Python 2.7.11 running on an Windows Server 2012 R2.

I've searched for similar problems but haven't found any solution. A similar question is asked in [what is the encoding of the subprocess module output in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28941133/3136474), but no viable solution is offered.

I read that Python 3 changed the way string and encoding works, but upgrading to Python 3 is not an option currently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If Python 3 isn't an option, then you'll have to use ctypes. In Python 2 `Popen` calls WinAPI `CreateProcessA`. The "A" suffix means this function decodes the command-line as an ANSI string (e.g. codepage 1252 in Western Europe) into a native UTF-16LE string. Almost all string handling in Windows and the kernel is UTF-16LE. The non-Unicode codepage encodings are a legacy from DOS and Windows 9x. Their primary use nowadays is to transform UTF-8 into meaningless mojibake...

Comment: In Python 3, `Popen` calls `CreateProcessW`, passing the command line as a native, UTF-16LE string. The CMD shell is also a Unicode application (since 1993) that calls wide-character `CreateProcessW`.

Comment: When CMD has to encode and decode strings (e.g. reading a batch script), it uses the legacy console codepage. So it may be possible to run `cmd /k chcp.com 65001` with stdin set to a pipe, and then pipe it the command line as a UTF-8 string.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work, so it's back to ctypes. After changing the console codepage, CMD does try to decode the piped string as UTF-8, but it does so one byte at a time while reading from the pipe, rather than decoding a line at a time. Obviously this fails for non-ASCII characters that use 2-4 bytes per character.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks, that's some useful information. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it... Comments on stackoverflow are somewhat transient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `subprocess.Popen` in Python 2 is calling the Windows function `CreateProcessA` which accepts a byte string in the currently configured code page. Luckily Python has an encoding type `mbcs` which stands in for the current code page.

```
cmd = u'C:\Python27\python.exe C:\path_to\script.py -n "Testç on ã and ê"'.encode('mbcs')
```

Unfortunately you can still fail if the string contains characters that can't be encoded into the current code page.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Mark. I'll try it out in a few days and accept your answer.

Comment: A few days later, tried it now and it worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot Mark.