# Python - how to convert unicode filename to CP437?

Tags: python, unicode, zip

I have a file that has a Unicode name, say `'קובץ.txt'`. I want to pack him, and I'm using python's [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html).

I can zip the files and open them later on with a problem except that file names are messed up when using windows 7 file explorer to view the files (7zip works great).

According to the docs, this is a common problem, and there are instructions on how to deal with that:

> From ZipFile.write
>
> **Note**
>
> There is no official file name encoding for ZIP files. If you have
>   unicode file names, **you must convert them to byte strings in your
>   desired encoding** before passing them to write(). WinZip interprets all
>   file names as encoded in CP437, also known as DOS Latin.

Sorry, but I can't seem to get what exactly am I supposed to do with the filename. I've tried `.encode('CP437')`, `.decode('CP437')`..

Comment: `zipfile` module uses utf-8 encoding instead of cp437 for non-ascii filenames  and sets `flag_bits | 0x800` while compressing. utf-8 encoding supports the full Unicode range (ignoring lone surrogates). You can both compress/decompress the file using Python. Or use `-mcu` switch to decompress it using 7-zip. See also, [Correctly decoding zip entry file names — CP437, UTF-8 or?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13261347/4279)

Comment: change the title of your question, to be more closely related to your actual task e.g., "create a zip archive with non-ascii entries". Where does `'קובץ.txt'` come from? Is it given as a command line argument? What is your python version? What happens if you run from the command-line: `py -mzipfile -c archive.zip קובץ.txt` in a directory that contains `קובץ.txt` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd have to encode your Unicode string to CP437. However, you can't encode your specific example because the CP437 codec does not support Hebrew:

```
>>> u'קובץ.txt'.encode('cp437')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
```

The above error tells you that the first 4 characters (`קובץ`) cannot be encoded because there are no such characters in the target characterset. CP437 only supports the western alphabet (A-Z, and accented characters like ç and é), IBM line drawing characters (such as ╚ and ┤) and a few greek symbols, mainly for math equations (such as Σ and φ).

You'll either have to generate a different filename that only uses [characters supported by the CP437 codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters) or live with the fact that WinZip will never be able to show Hebrew filenames properly, and simply stick with the characterset that did work for you with 7zip.

Comment: Thanks.

I think I need to rephrase my question, I'm using windows 7 to test and I think windows explorer is the program I'm using to open the a file.
Anyway, I'm able to create zip file that contains Hebrew text with a program, like "Total commander", I just can't create the same thing with python's zipfile

Comment: @A-Palgy: you'll need to show more information on how you do that then, like exactly what type of objects your filenames are (encoded strings, or `unicode` objects, for example). When you use Total commander to create a zip file, what does that look like in WinZip? What codec is used for the filenames, do you know? You'll have to use the same codec from Python.

Comment: How can I check what codec is used for the filenames?

Comment: What does the raw data look like when you open that zipfile? `repr(name)` would give you a re-usable representation of the bytes (in Python 2). It should be immediately clear if UTF-8 or UTF-16 was used, for example.

Comment: repr of the file name looks like this: `'\\'_\\xf4_\\xf5_\\xbf_\\xf0_\\xf5_\\xac _\\xa3_\\xf4_\\xf6_____\\xf4 #12.xlsx\\''` which should have been `הוראותלהזמנה #12.xlsx`
Thanks anyway, I think I'll stick with 7zip for now

Comment: @A-Palgy: that's not a valid `repr()`; that looks doubly quoted and the single quotes around it don't work with single quotes in the value. The `\xhh` byte count doesn't match your expected output either, I'm afraid. Last but not least, I can't find any correlation with any Hebrew-capable codecs that Python can handle out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import zipfile
p=b'\xd7\xa7\xd7\x95\xd7\x91\xd7\xa5.txt'.decode('utf8')
# or just:
# p='קובץ.txt'
z=zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip','w')
f=z.open(p.encode('utf8').decode('cp437'),'w')
f.write(b'hello world')
f.close()
z.close()
```

I've tried on a MacOSX, so it's not cp437 above, but utf8, and it works

I hope this works on windows

I've tested reading Chinese filenames with "gbk" or "gb18030" encoding with similar codes. And it works well.

When you have a zip archive from (or needs to send it to) Mac/Linux, change cp437 in the code to utf8 and everything works

When you have a zip archive from (or needs to send it to) Windows, leave cp437 unchanged

Answer (score 0):

For CP866 (Russian) this works:

```
    from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo

    class ZipInf(ZipInfo):
        def __init__(self, filename):
            super().__init__(filename)
            self.create_system = 0
        def _encodeFilenameFlags(self):
            return self.filename.encode('cp866'), self.flag_bits

    with ZipFile('ex.zip', 'w') as zipf:
        zipf.writestr(ZipInf('Файл'), '123456789'*1024)
```

It saves dirs and filenames in zip cp866 encoded (here is only 'Файл' file).